# Trying to get property of non-object laravel on command dispatch

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, command

I am using "Mapping Command Properties From Requests"  getting this error

**Trying to get property of non-object**

My Code

```
use App\Command\CreateSomethingCommand;

public function store(Request $request)
{
$this->dispatchFrom(CreateSomethingCommand::class,$request,['user'=>Auth::User()->id]);
.....
}
```

Where as the command stated at laravel 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus#dispatching-commands

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely triggered by this part of your code `Auth::User()->id`. If the user is not logged in then the result of `Auth::user()` will be `null` and since `null` is not an object you can't access the `id` property on it, thus throwing the exception:

> Trying to get property of non-object

To fix that you can use `Auth::id()` which will return the ID of the logged in user or `null` otherwise, but you'll avoid the exception.